# Python - Tuple out of range

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tuples, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract some data from a Redshift DB using the below Python script but it throws an error

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Given below is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

def func(name):
    db_details
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql.SQL("""select id,name,shop 
    from sales where shop = {}""").format(sql.Literal(name)))
```

Could anyone help as to why I am getting this error.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback instead of just that line?

Comment: Also, that sample is syntactically wrong, or incomplete

Comment: You are missing `"""` at the end if I am not wrong.

Comment: Sorry for missing out on the quotes on the end, missed them while writing my question I have updated them. Also I gave in a sample SQL as I have a bunch of sub-queries that make up the SQL but the final output has these 3 columns. Not sure if this would help.

Comment: What is the value of `name`